# How to programmatically create an OrientDB database of a given (json) schema?

Tags: json, orientdb

For my dev workflow purposes, I'd like to create a new orientdb database given a JSON schema, on the fly. I dont believe this is natively supported in orientdb, are there any existing solutions that do this - provide a JSON schema and point to a orientdb instance, and it auto-creates the database (edges, vertices, indexes and perhaps some sample data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating a .sh script to create the DB on the fly. The .sh files looks something like:

```
# (file: createmydb.sh)

# script to create my database declaratively

set echo true

# use this to ignore errors and continue, if needed
# set ignoreErrors true

# create database
create database plocal:../databases/MyDB root root plocal graph

# create User vertex
create class User extends      V

create property User.Email                  STRING
create property User.Firstname              STRING
...
```

And then call it like:

```
/usr/local/src/orientdb/bin/console.sh createmydb.sh
```

This works well for my purposes. The DB creation script is very easy to read, can be modified easily. And I am sure very backwards compatible (which may not have been the case with importing an exported JSON version of the db schema).

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found that pre-loading the schema using an external definition stored in either JSON or OSQL has been most successful for me. Currently I am using an OSQL script that contains a whole bunch of `CREATE CLASS ...` and `CREATE PROPERTY ...` commands. It works well enough.

Pretty soon I'll have to start supporting dynamic changes to the data model, at which point I will have to write code to read a JSON schema definition and convert that to appropriate calls into OrientDB, either through the Blueprints API or through SQL batches.

I've not found a tool that does what you need "automatically." If you find one, please let me (and everyone else here) know.

Comment: My solution is similar to yours but it uses shell scripting thru console.sh, instead of OSQL. Works well.